# how can I use ember routeTo event?

Tags: ember.js

from ember.js documentation, for RC4:

> LINKTO NOW GENERATES ROUTETO EVENTS
>
> Previously, the {{linkTo}} helper caused the router to transition
>   without any hooks to affect that behavior. Thanks to the work of Alex
>   Matchneer, the {{linkTo}} helper now generates a routeTo event that
>   can be handled just like any other event in a controller or a route's
>   events object. The default behavior of transitioning to the specified
>   route remains unchanged.

I don't understand how I can use it. I tried to do something like this:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend
  routeTo: -> alert "hello"
```

but it's never fired when i click a link.

My goal was rolling back transactions when i leave a route

Comment: could you try to add it in the ApplicationRoute's events hash, to see if it's just a problem in the controller ? (this should be something like `App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ events: {routeTo: function(){console.log('bla')}}})` I'll try to setup a jsfiddle too.

Comment: no... nothing changed. But you should be right, as described here: https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should have been in the blog post, but you need to enable a flag on the ENV object. This would work:

```
Ember.ENV.ENABLE_ROUTE_TO = true
```

That said, `routeTo` might be short-lived as the next iteration of the router API is fully realized. Most likely, all transitions will fire an event that can be intercepted to halt the transition, and likely the event will be called `willTransition`. But this is not 100% solidified, so be sure to subscribe to https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589 for the latest.

### update

I also totally missed out on the other part of your question (or maybe it was updated later), but routeTo is not a property you define on the controller, but rather an event that gets fired on the routes. So instead of having it on the controller, you'd do

```
App.SomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  events:
    routeTo: -> alert "hello"
```

But you wouldn't want this on ApplicationRoute since that's where the default-installed routeTo handler lives to perform the transition for you. The whole purpose of routeTo is to catch the event on a leafier route and possibly prevent it from happening.

### important caveat

Just want to reiterate that this is a very short-lived feature of the API (it was somewhat experimental anyway, hence the fact that it was wrapped in a flag). In the [next iteration of the router API](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589), routeTo will likely be replaced by a `willTransition` event, at which I'll update this answer.

Comment: Should'nt be Ember.ENV.ENABLE_ROUTE_TO = true ?

Comment: I think Ember.ENV gets set to the global ENV object at load time; sometimes it matters to have the global object set before Ember loads, but perhaps in this case it doesn't.

Comment: I'm  not sure how it is intended to work. In the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/eT9Gc/3/ we have to set Ember.ENV, but not sure it's the right way in an app, since before loading, Ember is not yet defined... anyway, this should fix the author's problem :)

Comment: but your fiddle's not printing anything in console. I'll try to put it in the routes and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to roll back transactions when you leave a route, you can use the deactivate hook as detailed here: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_deactivate

This is called just before the route exits.

Something like this:

```
App.MyFavouriteRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  deactivate: function() {
    //roll back your transaction here
    console.log('deactivating my favourite route');
  }
});
```

Note that this isn't called if you simply change the model... ie: if you transition from /myFavourite/1 to /myFavourite/2 then deactivate won't be called.... however if you transition to /myFavourites then it will be called

Comment: the issue that it's not called when i simply change my model is the reason i  was looking for something like the `routeTo` event